# Alignment issue in top posts section in the profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

There is an alignment issue in the **Top Posts** section of the [Profile tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile)

Previously **All** was showing first and there was an separator in between the Votes and Answers. Looks like some CSS code was break.

This issue occurred in all over the Stack Exchange communities.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Top Posts - alignment issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. This was an issue of a `float: right;` being applied to `.subtabs a` and `.filter a`. Unfortunately we only want it applied to `.subtabs a`. This will be corrected in the next production build.

Comment: *Correct me if I'm wrong.* Previously _status-completed_ tag was added after the code change went to production build. Recently when the issue is solved you are changing to status-completed, this is causing little confusion. Can be the status change only if the code change moved to build.

Comment: @Arulkumar Sure. It doesn't matter to me. The change is in the next production build queue, which should happen shortly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding :)

Comment: Working fine in the MSE `rev 2017.5.31.26108`.